# Simple HTML/PHP - Module Position

Tags: php, html, css, module, alignment

On my website(http://rsoracle.com/index.php) the module on the right side(Most Voted Server) is too low. I've been getting at it for a while and cannot figure it out. I was wondering if any one had any tips or solutions for my problem. Any help is appreciated!

Here is the appropriate codes: http://pastebin.com/iFSfB0Ye

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must **describe the specific problem** — and **include valid code** to reproduce it — in the question itself. See [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org/) for guidance.

Comment: Why is this tagged with `php`, but not with `css`?

Comment: Here is the code for the module:      <ul class="pull-right">
        <div class="span3">
          <div class="well sidebar-nav"><div class="container-fluid">
                  <div class="caption">
                    <h3>Most-Voted Server</h3>
                    <p><?php                                                                                                                                             Good question.

Comment: That doesn't help. That is not "Self Contained" - based on that, I presume you didn't click the SSCCE link in my last comment. Recreate your problem using as minimal code as possible on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an issue of div. You must merge row-fluid and pull-right class and then need to set the position of voted server  box. You may use Inspect Element option(it comes on right click of browser). To check and experiment the css. or may use stylebot add on of chrome.

Comment: "it comes on right click of browser" - only in Chrome; not Firefox, IE, Opera, Safari, etc.

Comment: @DannyBeckett: This option also comes in firefox too.